# Lxml replace tag by multiple others, in place

Tags: python, lxml

So im using LXML to parse/edit an XML file, which looks something like

```
<abc>
   <metadata x="..." y="..." z="...">
   ...
</abc>
```

and would like to replace it (in place) with

```
<abc>
   <tag key=x value="...">
   <tag key=y value="...">
   <tag key=z value="...">
   ...
</abc>
```

How do I do this. I've extracted the x,y,z tags but now need to figure out how to create 3 more tags with this data and insert it back into the etree.

Comment: New elements are created using `etree.Element()` or `etree.SubElement()`. https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-element-class

Comment: How do I then add these new elements as siblings?

Comment: Nevermind, just found the parent and did parent.insert

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
xml = '''
<abc>
   <metadata x="111" y="222" z="333" />
   ...
</abc>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
metadata = doc.metadata
doc = SimplifiedDoc('<abc></abc>')
abc = doc.abc
for key in metadata:
  if key=='tag' or key=='html':
    continue
  abc.appendChild('<tag key="{0}" value="{1}" />'.format(key,metadata[key]))

print (doc.html)
```

Result:

```
<abc><tag key="x" value="111" /><tag key="y" value="222" /><tag key="z" value="333" /></abc>
```